# iTunes connect Arabic localization

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store-connect, arabic

I'm trying to use Arabic description and metadata for my app. In iTunes connect it states that these data must be in English, so I did put them in English. Then i found the localization feature but found it doesn't support Arabic language.

However I found many apps that use Arabic in their names, meta data and description in the Saudi Arabia app store. I wonder how to do that?

Comment: It blows my mind that in March 2017 Apple _still_ don't allow itunes listings to be localised to Arabic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They just put their arabic description under 'English'. ITC says that it has to be in English, but I have 2 applications in the App Store with all the information in Polish.

Just put this info in Arabic, Apple will not reject your app because of that.

Comment: Thank you so much. You read my mind. I was afraid they may reject it if i used Arabic instead of English there.

Comment: Please don't do this -- use the standard localization infrastructure provided by Apple. See my answer below.

Comment: @Answerbot The problem is that the standard localization infrastructure in iTC does not support Arabic (it does however support it in iOS itself, which makes it all the more frustrating: you can't show on iTC that your app supports Arabic).

Comment: What if I add two English languages Eng US and Eng UK and add Arabic description in English UK section?

Comment: @IdreesAshraf Then only users in UK will see Arabic description, but I recommend against it because the rest of the world will see English anyway.

Comment: what about arabic app name and screenshots?
i think apple have huge problem there

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, Apple keeps a weirdly different list of languages for the App Store and for the iOS app itself. You can localize your *app* into Arabic, but the *iTunes description* cannot be. The best method is to paste it into the English description and use it for all languages.

You can see a complete language list for iOS and the App Store, which explains which languages are available on each, here:

http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html

Arabic is the last on that list, marked as Yes for iOS, and No for App Store.

Comment: What do we do if we want to localize both a foreign language (that is not showing up) and English? How can we do both simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

The Arabic language has been added to App Store Connect.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answers works great, but what if my app is bilingual (english, arabic), what do you think is the best thing to do? I think the best solution is to set the arabic language instead of any other language except for english, and set it as a primary language.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I have an app that does the same thing (support both Arabic and English). In the app description I have both languages - first Arabic (since that is my main target group) then in English just below.