# How to localise an arabic app in iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to use Arabic description and metadata for my app.

In iTunes connect it states that these data must be in English or any other languages, so I did put them in English.

The development of my app(storyboard and content) is in arabic.So when I went to submit the app in iTunes connect
I didn't found Arabic language support!

My question is how can I submit arabic details for the app name,description and screenshots?!

Thanks

Comment: Hope this helps you: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090602/itunes-connect-arabic-localization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes does not support Arabic. I faced with that issue before. So theoretically you could not do it but someone suggested me to do it like that:
Just use arabic in some other languages(e.g French) and it will work. Also Apple won't reject your app because of that.
I know its not that good solution but currently we do not have anything more to do.

Comment: Ok.I already did that and I submitted my app metadata in arabic using the English language.

But, the users got confused and in iTunes connect I got a lot of AppStore Views in the US and Saudi Arabia but what I found is that the users in the US didn't converts and download the app because it's in arabic.

I want to keep both an arabic and english version of my app metadata.

Can I just change the metadata in COMPLETE English(to not confuse US users)  and cut -paste the arabic metadata that was in the English language in another language like French without loosing  app store ranking of my app?

Comment: I think you can do it. As I said in my previous comment just choose another language and put arabic

Comment: OK.I'll try this.
Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

The Arabic language has been added to App Store Connect.
[image]