# How to add arabic screenshot and text in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

We've developed an app that supports a couple of languages. And everything is fine, the app is approved by Apple for the first couple of languages.

We've recently added support for Arabic, and now when I'm trying to add the App information on App Store Connect for Arabic, I'm stuck.

https://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html
states that Arabic is not supported as a "App Store language"

How do I add Arabic keywords, screenshot, description on App Store Connect?

There's a lot of languages that are not supported, e.g: Polish, Czech, Ukranian, Hindi and so on.

I don't know if it's of any interest but we've developed the app with Xamarin.iOS

How do you guys do it?

I've seen a couple of threads that suggests that I should add the arabic text, screenshots keywords and so, on other languages that we're not using. But doesn't feel like a correct solution. 
(Source: [iTunes connect Arabic localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090602/itunes-connect-arabic-localization) , [How to localise an arabic app in iTunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938773/how-to-localise-an-arabic-app-in-itunes-connect))

So, how do you do it?

Any tips?
Thank you!

Comment: If a language is not supported by App Store Connect, you cannot localize the App Store metadata to that language - unfortunately, there is no way around this. However, keep in mind that iOS does support the Arabic language, so you can still localize your app and it will be shown for users that chose Arabic as their preferred language.

Comment: @TamásSengel thanks for your reply. But look at this app: 
[link](https://itunes.apple.com/qa/app/%D9%82%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AA/id608065932?mt=8) . How did they add the text and screenshots? Did they add it in another language?

Comment: This app only has Arabic App Store metadata. They provided only one translation in place of a randomly chosen language (English, for example) and made that the primary language. This works if the app is monolingual *or* if you don't want to translate the app to the primary language - but that also means that users will see the Arabic metadata for **every** language without metadata translation. That's why the primary language is usually English - it's an internet standard, so to say.

Comment: @TamásSengel is it common for App Store Connect to add more languages every now and again? I have a similar problem, albeit in a different language, and I'm curious if it will be possible if I come back to it again at some point in the future.

Comment: @user Yes, they do add new languages from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arabic language has been added to App Store Connect. [image]